# Oracle Query: Two/Multiple simple IF condition blocks in the same SQL file not executing

Tags: database, oracle, if-statement, toad, pls-00103

The SQL file contains Two simple IF conditions, but it is not executing in TOAD:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(COLUMNNAME1) FROM TABLENAME1 WHERE COLUMNNAME1 = 'UNIQUEID1') > 0)
BEGIN
(UPDATE QUERY1)
END;

IF (SELECT COUNT(COLUMNNAME1) FROM TABLENAME1 WHERE COLUMNNAME1 = 'UNIQUEID2') > 0)
BEGIN
(UPDATE QUERY2)
END;
```

But these are individually executing successfully, please let me know if the query is missing something.

Executed successfully and IF condition passes to update the table in the database

Comment: IF ? not a SQL statement and in PL/SQL should end with "END IF" not "END" + the whole code should be in a "BEGIN/END" block.

Answer (score 0):

Should be more like this:

```
BEGIN        
    IF (SELECT COUNT(COLUMNNAME1) FROM TABLENAME1 
         WHERE COLUMNNAME1 = 'UNIQUEID1') > 0 THEN
        UPDATE QUERY1;
    END IF;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(COLUMNNAME1) FROM TABLENAME1 
         WHERE COLUMNNAME1 = 'UNIQUEID2') > 0 THEN
        UPDATE QUERY2;
    END IF;
END;
```

You may want to commit your changes somewhere in this script, too.